# Images.xcassets - some folders not visible/show in xcode

Tags: xcode

Suddenly, xcode does not show me all folders/directories in Images.xcassets.

How do I get them to show back?

Comment: Please provide some more information e.g. xcode version

Comment: File>Open Quickly. Type your file or folder name. May be this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below given steps:

1. Go to the project folder in the Finder. You should find that the folder Images.xcassets is still there.
2. Move it to a separate location like to the Desktop or something. It still has all of the images and json files. //// IF it does not have all of the images and son files then let me know.
3. Jump back to Xcode and create a new asset catalog for images.
4. File > New > File... > Resource > Asset Catalog

Name it Images.

5. Quit Xcode and return to the Finder.
6. Copy the folders from within your old Images.xcassets to the new Images.xcassets directory in your project